# PDO_OCI in php script not working in cronjob (crontab), but works when executed by user directly

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, cron, sles

A php 5.5.14 script that connects to a database in order to retrieve data and send it to a webservice works fine when executed in the console, but doesn't work in the cronjob (crontab). When the cronjob executes the script, the database connection via pdo_oci driver isn't established and instead the exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[]: (null)' is thrown.

I've already tried multiple things to find the error but nothing worked. Firstly I checked the php installation via php -m and php -v in the cronjob and compared the modules and version to the php version when called as user. The installed modules and version were identical. Secondly I let the cronjob run under my user with su -u user crontab -e. Then I logged all the credentials and everything to make sure that the connection string is identical to the one when called directly. The connection string proved to be identical. I just can't comprehend why the script would run when executed directly in the console but doesn't in the cronjob.

Following line establishes the connection to the database via pdo_oci driver:

```
 $con = new PDO('oci:dbname='//dburl:port/dbserver, dbuser, dbpassword);
```

The script is executed as follows via crontab:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/script/phpscript.php -params
```

As stated before, usually the connection is established, but when run via cronjob the exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[]: (null)' is thrown. Oddly enough the script is already running on another server and everything works fine there.

I am aware that the php version used is extremely old, my job is to make a 1:1 migration and I am not allowed to upgrade the php version.

Comment: In meantime I added a systemd timer and removed the cronjob, sadly it didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution, should anyone ever have the same problem this may maybe help you. Per accident I discovered, that the system somehow used another version of the oracle instant client than my user. Somehow even if the script was called with my user in the cronjob it didn't matter, as it would always use the wrong version. Make sure that you only installed the correct version of the oracle instant client and that only that version is exported as library path.